# how to know what are the input devices connected to the system

Tags: java, hardware

iam just simply trying to know what are the input devices and output devices connected to the system. Do there any api to get information about input/output devices using java?

**EDIT**

independent of any operating system.

Please suggest.

Comment: for which OS you are trying to implement it?

Comment: @Marko input devices likw Keyboard, mic and mouse etc <br> output devices like display devices

Answer (score 2):

To find what usb devices are connected to the system you can use [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/). This [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/index.html) has more in-depth information on how to use the api. In particular, to find all usb devices (slightly modified from the article):

```
Host host = HostFactory.getHost();
// Obtain a list of the USB buses available on the Host.
Bus[] bus  = host.getBusses();

// Traverse through all the USB buses.
for (int i = 0; i < bus.length; i++) {
    // Access the root hub on the USB bus and obtain the number of USB ports available on the root hub.
    Device root = bus[i].getRootHub();
    int totalPorts = root.getNumPorts();

    // Traverse through all the USB ports available on the 
    // root hub. It should be mentioned that the numbering 
    // starts from 1, not 0.
    for (int j=1; j<=total_port; j++) {
        // Obtain the Device connected to the port.
        Device device = root.getChild(j);
        if (device != null) {
                    // USB device available, do something here.
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can use the api for MIDI systems to find what MIDI devices are connected, see [the java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing-MIDI.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try commandline via java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`

According to this site http://michaelminn.com/linux/command_line
Following command should return this:

```
lspci: Lists information about devices connected to the internal PCI busses.

lspci -vv: Full dump of information.
```

so

```
String command="lspci";
```

And from windows you may need to download DevCon command! http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/EN-US

so

```
String command="devcon find";
```